# Meaning of inner product $\langle \vec{r} | \psi(t)\rangle $

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, hilbert-space

I have come across the equation which comes out of the nothing  in Zettili's book *Quantum mechanics concepts and applications* p. 167:

$$\psi(\vec{r},t) ~=~ \langle \vec{r} \,|\, \psi(t) \rangle.$$

How do I know that I get *function of position and time* if i take an inner product of a state vector with an vector $\vec{r}$? Where is the proof?

Comment: So, you have a function of t (in terms of t only, no other variable), apply the inner product with r. The result could only be in terms of r and t, right? One or the other may be absent, but in general r and t are the only two variable we could have. So how could we not call that a function of r and t?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The proof is probably not the right word since the expression $\Psi(x,t) = \langle{x}|{\Psi(t)}\rangle$ is actually the **definition** of position space wave function.

### Basis in finite dimensional vector space

Any vector $|v\rangle$ from some finite dimensional vector space $V(F)$ can be written as a linear combination of basis vectors $|e_{i}\rangle$ from an ordered basis $( |e_{i}\rangle )_{i=1}^{n}$
$$
|v\rangle = \sum\limits_{i}^{n} c_{i} |e_{i}\rangle \, , \quad  (1)
$$
where $c_{i} \in F$.

And we say that with respect to chosen ordered basis $( |e_{i}\rangle )_{i=1}^{n}$ any vector $|v\rangle$ can be uniquely **represented** by an ordered collection, or $n$-tuple of the coefficients in its linear expansion over the basis 
$$
|v\rangle \longleftrightarrow ( c_{i} )_{i=1}^{n} \, .
$$

### Finite dimensional inner product spaces

Now if we have a special kind of a vector space - an inner product space - a vector space with an inner product, i.e. a map $I(|v\rangle, |w\rangle)$ of the following form
\begin{equation}
    I(|v\rangle, |w\rangle): V(F) \times V(F) \to {F} \, , 
\end{equation}
with some properties defined for any two vectors $|v\rangle$ and $|w\rangle$ from the vectors space, we know how the coefficients $c_{i}$ looks like.
Taking the inner product of both sides of equation (1) with some basis vector $|e_{j}\rangle$ gives
$$
I(|e_{j}\rangle, |v\rangle) = \sum\limits_{i}^{n} c_{i} I(|e_{j}\rangle, |e_{i}\rangle) \, . \quad (2)
$$
Now since we can always orthonormalize our basis set so that
$$
I(|e_{j}\rangle, |e_{i}\rangle) = \delta_{ji} \, ,
$$
where $\delta_{ji}$ is the Kronecker delta
\begin{equation}
    \delta_{ji} = 
    \left\{ 
        \begin{matrix} 
            0, & \text{if } j \neq i \, ; \\
            1, & \text{if } j = i \, .
        \end{matrix} 
    \right. 
\end{equation}
equation (2) becomes
$$
I(|e_{j}\rangle, |v\rangle) = c_{j} \, .
$$

That is it basically. Each coefficient $c_{i}$ in equation (1) in inner product space is given by $I(|e_{i}\rangle, |v\rangle)$.

Oh, and if the inner product space is complete, i.e. it is a Hilber space, than we almost always use the following notation for an inner product
$$
I(|v\rangle, |w\rangle) = \langle v | w \rangle \, ,
$$
which is another story and so with respect to chosen ordered basis $( |e_{i}\rangle )_{i=1}^{n}$ any vector $|v\rangle$ in Hilbert space can be uniquely **represented** by an ordered collection, or $n$-tuple, of the coefficients $c_{i}$ given by $\langle e_{i} | v \rangle$
$$
|v\rangle \longleftrightarrow ( \langle e_{i} | v \rangle )_{i=1}^{n} \, .
$$

### Infinite dimensional Hilbert space

We have infinite dimensional complex Hilbert space $H(\mathbb{C})$ and we would like to expand the state vector $|\Psi(t)\rangle$ over a set of eigenvectors of some self-adjoint operator which represent some observable.

If the spectrum of self-adjoint operator $\hat{A}$ is **discrete** then one can label eigenvalues using some discrete variable $i$
\begin{equation}
    \hat{A} |a_{i}\rangle = a_{i} |a_{i}\rangle \, ,
\end{equation}
and expansion of the state vector has the following form
$$
|\Psi(t)\rangle = \sum\limits_{i}^{\infty} c_{i}(t) |a_{i}\rangle, \quad \text{where} \quad c_{i}(t) = \langle a_{i} | \Psi(t) \rangle \, .
$$
So you have a a set of discrete coefficients $c_{i}(t)$ which can be used to represent the state vector. Each $c_{i}$ is basically complex number, but this number is different at different times and so it is written as $c_{i}(t)$.

But if the spectrum of self-adjoint operator is **continuous** then it is not possible to use discrete variable to label the eigenvalues, rather $a$ in the eigenvalue equation
\begin{equation}
    \hat{A} |a\rangle = a |a\rangle \, ,
\end{equation}
should be interpreted as continuous variable which is used to label eigenvalues and corresponding eigenvectors and expansion of the state vector looks like
\begin{equation}
    |\Psi(t)\rangle = \int\limits_{a_{min}}^{a_{max}} c(a,t) |a\rangle \, \mathrm{d}a, \quad \text{where} \quad c(a,t) = \langle a | \Psi(t) \rangle \, .
\end{equation}
So the the coefficients in the expansion are given not by a set of complex numbers labeled using discrete variable but rather as a complex-valued function of continuous variable. But this function $c(a,t)$ plays the same role: it determines the coefficients in the expansion. This time, however, you need a coefficient for each and every value of continuous variable $a$ and that's why they are given by a function. And again these coefficients different at different times.

Position operator $\hat{X}$ has continuous spectrum.
In the the simplest case - one particle in one spatial dimension - variable $x$ in
$$
\hat{X} |x\rangle  = x |x\rangle \, ,
$$
represents a position of the particle and runs over all possible values of position in one spatial dimension, i.e. $x \in \mathbb{R}$, and state vector is expanded over the set of eigenvectors $|x\rangle$ as
\begin{equation}
    |\Psi(t)\rangle = \int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \Psi(x,t) |x\rangle \,\mathrm{d}x, \quad \text{where} \quad \Psi(x,t) = \langle{x}|{\Psi(t)}\rangle \, .
\end{equation}

Comment: It is well written, but doesnt anwser my question. Maybe i was missunderstood. So i ll try again: Why do we say that $\Psi (x,t) = \langle x|\psi(t) \rangle$ and why not for example anything else like: $\Psi (x,t) = x^t$ or $\Psi (x,t) = \frac{x}{t}$. I don't get it why among all possibilities we chose the inner product?

Comment: @71GA kemiisto actually does an excellent job of addressing that very question; when we define the function $\Psi$ in this way, then it is precisely the representation of the Hilbert space vector $|\psi\rangle$ in the "basis" $|x\rangle$.  If you were to pick some other random definition, then the resulting function would in general have no relationship whatsoever with the state $|\psi\rangle$: +1 kemiisto.

Comment: @71GA that is pretty simple. It is just the way it is in inner product spaces. I've expanded my answer, but I highly recommend you to read something about the basics of linear algebra.

Answer (score 20):

There is nothing to prove; this just involves making definitions as follows:

Let an element $|\psi\rangle$ of the Hilbert space $\mathcal H$ of a particle moving in three dimensions be given.  Let $|\mathbf x\rangle$ denote a simultaneous eigenstate of the position operators $X,Y,Z$ corresponding to eigenvalues $x,y,z$ where $\mathbf x = (x,y,z)$.  Then for each $\mathbf x\in\mathbb R^3$, the inner product
$$
  \langle \mathbf x|\psi\rangle
$$
is a complex number.  We can therefore *define* a function $\psi:\mathbb R^3\to\mathbb C$ as follows:
$$
  \psi(\mathbf x) = \langle \mathbf x|\psi\rangle
$$
If, instead, $|\psi(t)\rangle$ is a function $\mathbb R\to\mathcal H$ mapping $t\mapsto |\psi(t)\rangle$, then for each $(t,\mathbf x)\in \mathbb R\times\mathbb R^3$ the inner product
$$
  \langle \mathbf x|\psi(t)\rangle
$$
is a complex number, and we *define* a function $\psi:\mathbb R\times\mathbb R^3\to\mathbb C$ by
$$
  \psi(t,\mathbf x) = \langle \mathbf x|\psi(t)\rangle
$$

The motivation for these definitions is that when the function $\psi$ is defined in this way, it is the representation of the state $|\psi\rangle$ in the "basis" $|\mathbf{x}\rangle$ consisting of eigenvectors of the position operator.

See user kemiisto's great discussion below for details!

Comment: There, now. Isn't that so much easier to follow? Some might even say it's an oversimplification of the problem. +1

Comment: @Jim Your comment pretty much said it all, but sometimes a little mathematical formalism can go a long way in convincing the skeptical :).

Comment: It's why I gave you the +1. I just thought the way you answered "how is g(r)*h(t)=f(r,t)?" was definitely the highlight of my day. It is right up there with when I learned the meaning of the word Hellenologophobia. Similarly, yours is a good answer but it requires someone to make a sarcastic comment.

Comment: @Jim Haha agreed.  I'm glad you took that imperative upon yourself.

Answer (score 4):

> I don't get it why among all possibilities we chose the inner product?

(1)  The position eigenstates are complete:

$$1 = \int \mathrm{d}x \, |x\rangle \, \langle x |$$

(2)  The state, expressed as a weighted "sum" of position eigenstates where the weights are given by the probability amplitude, i.e., the position wavefunction:

$$|\psi(t)\rangle = \int \mathrm{d}x \, |x\rangle \, \psi(x,t)$$

(3) Now, let (1) operate on the state:

$$|\psi(t)\rangle = \int \mathrm{d}x \, |x\rangle \, \langle x |\psi(t)\rangle $$

To see that:

$$\psi(x,t) = \langle x |\psi(t)\rangle$$

---

> Is this |x⟩⟨x| defined?

It is an operator that "projects" an arbitrary state "in the direction" of the state $|x\rangle$.  See, for example, [Projection Operators and Completeness](http://quantummechanics.ucsd.edu/ph130a/130_notes/node185.html).

> How did we get 2nd eq from first?

We didn't.  (2) simply expresses the fundamental property of a vector space that any state in the space can be expressed as the weighted sum of basis states.  For example, we could also write the state in terms of the *momentum* eigenstates:

$$|\phi(t)\rangle = \int \mathrm{d}k \, |k\rangle \, \phi(k,t)$$

where $\phi(k,t)$ is the momentum wavefunction and:

$$\phi(k,t) = \langle k |\phi(t)\rangle$$

Comment: Is this $|x\rangle \, \langle x |$ defined? We cant matrix multiply them can we? What is the meaning of this?

Comment: @71GA, yes, in Hilbert space, such kind of product between any two $| u \rangle$ and $\langle v |$ is defined and is known as the outer product. Outer product can be used to construct so-called projection operators: if the vector is the same inside both brackets $| u \rangle \langle u |$ and it represent some eigenstate of Hermitian operator than the action on such operator on arbitrary state vector $| \Psi \rangle$ is the projection of the state $| \Psi \rangle$ onto the eigenstate $| u \rangle$.

Comment: How did we get 2nd eq from first? Did we simply matrix multiply by $|\Psi(t)\rangle$? And after that we wrote $|x\rangle\, \langle x| \, |\Psi(t) \rangle = |x\rangle\, \langle x|\Psi(t) \rangle = |x\rangle\, \Psi(x,t)$?

Comment: And one more thing. When you write: $1 = \int \mathrm{d}x \, |x\rangle \, \langle x |$. Does this mean that the outer product $|x\rangle \langle x|$ is equal to the unitary matrix?

Comment: @71GA think about this in the following way. You start from the trivial equality $| \Psi(t) \rangle = \hat{I} | \Psi(t) \rangle$ and by writing $\hat{I}$ on the right side as $\int |x\rangle \langle x| \, \mathrm{d}x$ (that is called the resolution of identity) you end up with $| \Psi(t) \rangle = \int |x\rangle \langle x | \Psi(t) \rangle \, \mathrm{d}x$.

Comment: @71GA the matrix representation basically applicable only for finite-dimensional spaces, where each projection operator $\hat{P}_{i} = | e_{i} \rangle \langle e_{i} |$ (like any other operator) can be represented by $n \times n$ square matrix $\boldsymbol{P}_{i}$. But this matrix is not an identity matrix. Rather, the sum of all projection operators is identity operator $\sum_{i=1}^{n} \hat{P}_{i} = \hat{I}$ which correspond to the the sum of all corresponding matrices being identity matrix $\sum_{i=1}^{n} \boldsymbol{P}_{i} = \boldsymbol{I}$.

Comment: @71GA, see my answer updated to address your comments.